# Is a function on a ball of radius 1 around the zero vector bounded if it is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is a function on a ball of radius 1 around the zero vector bounded if it is continuous?

If yes/no, why is that?

Comment: Yes, because the ball is compact.

Comment: The ball is compact, so you can use [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces).

Comment: The topology-level property is that continuous images of compact sets are compact. Thus in a metric space the continuous image of a compact set is, in particular, bounded.

Comment: But since the set of a ball of radius 1 around the zero vector is an open set, couldn't a function be continuous on it but unbounded?

Comment: On the open ball, yes. We generally distinguish between the open ball and the closed ball explicitly because of this kind of thing. (Also, in general a closed ball in a metric space is not always compact, but it is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$.)

Comment: I think this works, but I'm not sure of the setting for this question and I'm not well-versed in function spaces or infinite-dimensional vector spaces. Take $f(x)=\tan(\|x\|^2\frac{\pi}{2})$, this is a real-valued function that tends toward infinity as you approach the boundary of the ball.

Answer (score 2):

If the ball is open, then you cannot say that the function is bounded. For example, consider the function $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on the open ball $B$ by
$$\text{for all } x\in B, \quad f(x) = \frac{1}{1-||x||}$$

This function is not bounded.

If however your function is defined on a whole finite-dimensional space, then it is also defined on the closed ball which is compact. Hence it is continuous on a compact, so it is bounded on it, and a fortiori, it is bounded on the open ball.

Comment: I know this is an old answer and question but I don't understand, if a function is continuous on an open ball, doesn't that mean that the function inside the ball is always bounded by the boundary of the ball, therefore it is bounded?

Comment: Bounded means that its values are bounded, not that the domain is bounded.